# нужно оптимизировать код

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Я еще учусь программировать на питоне и поэтому я решил написать большую программу вопросник в которую можно играть или вкладывать свои вопросы. От вас я прошу только говорить мои ошибки которые вы заметите и желательно писать их решение. Ну или просто сделать его более читабельным

```
    from random import randint
import sys

voprosi = {1:["q1","почему ты в это играешь? ",["хочу создать новые вопросы","хочу оптимизировать работу программы","просто так"],1],
2:["q4","почему вопрос четвертый если он обозначен как 2?",["автор еще не исправил этот баг","автор не будет ничего исправлять","ой все фигня ваш тест"],1]}
i = 1

def ad():    # команда для создания вопроса
    answ_vars = []
    tit = input("write a title of question: " )    # беру тему вопроса
    vopros = input("write vopros: " )    # сам вопрос
    print("write some answers")
    print("write 'ok' when it is complete!")
    while True:    # пишем ответы
        sss = input()
        if sss != "ok":
            answ_vars.append(sss)
            continue
        else:
            print("выберите правильный ответ")
            for f,s in enumerate(answ_vars):    # для написанных ответов выбрать правильный вариант
                print(f,s)
            right_answ = int(input())
            while right_answ > len(answ_vars)-1 or right_answ < 0:    # когда правильный ответ не в диапазоне, вылезает ошибка
                print("неверный ввод")
                right_answ = int(input())
            print("otlichna!")
            global voprosi     # хз что это наверно надо
            i = len(voprosi)+1
            voprosi[i] = [tit,vopros,answ_vars,right_answ]         # помещаем все под одни скобки
            print(voprosi[i])         # финальный вид вопроса
            break

def quiz():          # команда для игры
    if len(voprosi)<2:    # при вопросах меньше 2х возникает ошибка изза рандома)
        print("make more questions!!! ")
        return "Sucker"
    v = voprosi[randint(1,len(voprosi))]
    print("title: "+v[0])
    print("question: "+v[1])
    for k,g in enumerate(v[2]):
        print(k, "• "+g)
    while True:
        if int(input()) == v[3]:
            print("nice! ")
            break
        else:
            print("try again" )

def quig():
    sys.exit()

def popored(red=0,popo=0,item=0):
    if red == 1:    # редактирование вопроса в процессе разработки:)
        pass
    elif popo == 1: # удаление вопроса
        for i,t in enumerate(voprosi):
            print(i,voprosi[t])
        print("What number?: ")
        while True:
            p = int(input())
            if p not in range(len(voprosi)):
                print("choose an existing number")
                continue
            else:
                del voprosi[p]
                print(voprosi.items())
    elif item == 1:
        print(voprosi.items())



print("create some questions or complete it! ")

while True:
    a = input("введите START для игры, AD для добавления вопроса или QUIT для выхода: " )
    print("\n")
    if a == "quit".lower():
        quig()                     #выходим
    elif a == "start".lower():
        quiz()                     #пробуем играть
    elif a == "ad".lower():
        ad()                       #запускаем функцию для добавления вопроса
    elif a == "popo":
        popored(popo=1)            #удаление вопроса
    elif a == "item":
        popored(item=1)            #показ вопросов
```

Comment: Для начала прочитайте [`PEP 8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) ([перевод](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)) и улучшите код в соответствии с его рекомендациями, потому что в вашем коде 47 ошибок и 1 предупреждение связаны именно с форматированием кода.

Comment: большое спасибо! обязательно прочту

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import sys
import random


questions = [
    {
        'title': 'question_1_title',
        'text': 'question_1_text?',
        'answers': [
            'answer 1',
            'answer 2',
            'answer 3',
            'answer 4',
        ],
        'correct': 1,
    },
    {
        'title': 'question_2_title',
        'text': 'question_2_text?',
        'answers': [
            'answer 1',
            'answer 2',
            'answer 3',
            'answer 4',
        ],
        'correct': 2,
    },
]


def add_question():
    # Dialog for adding questions
    title = input("Write a title for question: ")
    text = input("Write question text: ")

    print("Write answers (Write OK when is complete): ")

    answers = list()
    answer = input("Write answer: ")

    while answer.lower() != 'ok':
        answers.append(answer)
        answer = input("Write one more answer: ")

    correct = input("Choice right answer: ")
    correct = int(correct)

    while 0 > correct > len(answers):
        correct = input("Wrong input try again: ")
        correct = int(correct)


    question = {
        'title': title,
        'text': text,
        'answers': answers,
        'correct': correct,
    }

    questions.append(question)


def del_question():
    NotImplemented


def lst_question():
    # List questions
    for question in questions:
        print(question['title'])
        print(question['text'])

        for answer in question['answers']:
            print('  ', answer)

        print(question['correct'])

        print('')


def ask_question():
    # Ask a question
    question = random.choice(questions)

    print(question['title'])
    print(question['text'])

    for i, answer in enumerate(question['answers']):
        print(f'{i} - {answer}')


    respons = input("Input your respons: ")
    respons = int(respons)

    while respons != question['correct']:
        respons = input("Try again: ")
        respons = int(respons)

    print('Excelent!!!')


def end():
    sys.exit()


def main():
    print('''Create questions or complete it!
    Commands:
        ADD - add question
        DEL - delete question
        LST - list questions
        ASK - start game
        END - exit
    ''')

    actions = {
        'add': add_question,
        'del': del_question,
        'lst': lst_question,
        'ask': ask_question,
        'end': end,
    }

    while True:
        command = input('Input command: ')
        action = actions.get(command.lower())

        if not action:
            print('Incorect command')
            continue

        action()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Удачи тебе в твоих начинаниях.